# How can I convert the Percentile_Disc in SQL to Spark Sql

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql, percentile, percentile-cont

At work we're moving from Teradata to Spark SQL (Hadoop Cluster), so I need to convert many of my scripts.

Here is my original SQL script, and I am trying to get the 60th percentile of the cust. satisfaction rating (i.e. top 40% of performers) for each call centre team we have.  I've tried variations of it online but i can't get it working:

```
***SELECT       BSE.staffgrouplevel                     
            ,BSE.Sub_Region
            ,BSE.staffgroup
            ,Percentile_Disc(0.6) Within GROUP (ORDER BY BSE.CSAT ASC) AS CSAT_pct_q60
                    
FROM        P_IntegratedAnalytics_T.Q121_BPL_EmpTgtRawData3         BSE
INNER JOIN  P_IntegratedAnalytics_T.Q121_60th_TOP_SCORE_FROM_PARTNER3       BSE2
ON          BSE.STAFFGROUP = BSE2.STAFFGROUP
AND         BSE.COMPANY = BSE2.COMPANY
AND         BSE.CSAT_Sg_Comp_60 = BSE2.CSAT_Sg_Comp_60
WHERE       BSE2.CSAT_Sg_Comp_60 = BSE2.Top_CSAT_Sg_Comp_60
AND         BSE.CSATDen>=10
GROUP BY    1,2,3***
```

Any advice or suggestions on what I should use here?